# JSON not returning anything in Volley

Tags: android, arrays, json, android-volley, jsonresponse

I am using volley and at the moment my `volley` is not returning anything.

This is my `JSON` array response:

```
{
  "forename": "Lukasz",
  "surname": "Pioetrszci"
}
```

In my `onResponse` method in `Volley` I have:

```
  JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest
                (URLgetUser, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>(){

                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONArray jsonArray) {
                        try {
                            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                                JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                                forename = jsonObject.getString("forename");
                            }
                        }
                        catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }
```

I believe it is to do with the fact that I only have

```
{
  "forename": "Lukasz",
  "surname": "Pioetrszci"
}
```

As opposed to

```
[
  {
      "forename": "Lukasz",
      "surname": "Pioetrszci"
  },
  {
      "forename": "Jack",
      "surname": "Rabin"
  },
  {
      "forename": "Anil",
      "surname": "Chopra"
  },
]
```

Comment: Yes. That is probably the reason. Also your log cat should probably show some stack trace, since you are catching the exception

Comment: LogCat doesn't show anything as the function returns a string. By default it returns `null` if nothing is found

Comment: check log cat and response using rest client like Postman.

Comment: Enclose your JSON data within [ and ] even if it is a single object, in order to be retrieved it as JSONarray. Can you provide the details on how the data is generated?

Comment: If the response is only `{
  "forename": "Lukasz",
  "surname": "Pioetrszci"
}`, you should use JsonObjectRequest instead

Answer (score 0):

You have to use

```
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(reponse);
        String forename = jsonObject.getString("forename")
        String surname = jsonObject.getString("surname")
```